# Can I sell computer with pre-installed software with Apache 2.0 License?

Tags: apache-2.0

Can I sell computer with pre-installed software with Apache 2.0 License? Provided that I do not charge for software or license, only for hardware with some margin?

Comment: Is there any reason why you think that might not be possible/permitted?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau perhaps the software+hardware is a derivative work? but apache allows selling so I don't see the problem there. Perhaps the source code must be supplied along with the computer?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau In Germany, the problem could be that you are allowed to ignore the license if you **run** software that you legally received. I don't know about the Apache license, but the consequences in the case of the AGPL are clear: You can operate some AGPL-licensed software-as-service without having to give others access to the source code.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly lawful to sell a computer with free software pre-installed.  Indeed, you may charge whatever you like; not just for the hardware, but for the software, too.  The FSF [are clear about that](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.html).

What you may not do is deliver it without user freedom, so you may not attempt to legally prevent the user from using, copying, modifying, and then redistributing the software thereon as they wish.  If the software is covered by a copyleft licence, such as GPL, you must provide the user with source code to assist them in this.  If the GPL is v3, you may not attempt to prevent the user exercising their freedoms by technical means (eg, DRM), either.